# Enabling Radiobuttons does not work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, radio-group

At some point in my project I need to check if a user is active or not. If the user is not active I need to disable everything in the main container, but leave some buttons enabled. Among them is a radio group with 2 buttons: `active` and `inactive`.

Firstly I call the jQuery Function `$("#main_cont *").attr("disabled", "disabled");` to disable all the elements and them I'm trying to enable the necessary one again.

Everything works fine until I test it in IE. In my code you can see that I remove the `disabled` attribute not only from the radio buttons, but I have a problem only with them. Thank you for help!

```js
function setInaktiveDisabled() {
  if (!document.getElementById("aktiv").checked) {
    $("#main_cont *").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#btn_history_back").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#aktiv").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#inaktiv").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#sp_verrechnung").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#btn_logout").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#btn_loeschen").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-4 ">
  <div id="div_aktiv" class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="aktiv" id="aktiv" onchange="change_user_status_auf_aktiv();">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="aktiv">aktiv</label>
  </div>
  <div id="div_inaktiv" class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="aktiv" id="inaktiv" onchange="change_user_status_auf_inaktiv();">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inaktiv">inaktiv</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I call this function in "$( document ).ready" after I've have filled all the fields with Data from the AJAX request. Where have you found the same IDs? It's only the part of HTML code. All code is in the main div. And as I have already written, everything works without problem in other browsers, this problem is only in IE...

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow :) Please visit [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how to properly ask a question.

Comment: By the way, your code snippet seems incomplete for us to help you, you're not calling the `setInaktiveDisabled` function anywhere in the snippet. Be sure to post a code snippet that allow us to reproduce the problematic situation.

Comment: Unfortunately all my Code in this JS file is too big and can confuse until you don't know what is it about. I just call the function setInaktiveDisabled() after document is ready to check if the user is active or no, And if no, I need to disable everything besides a few buttons. That is exactly what this function does. It disables all the elements in my main container, it also disables my radio group. But then I need to enable radio group again, what I also do in this function on the next line. But radio group stills disabled in IE and enabled in other browsers.